# SSRS email authentication error file not supported?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

we recently moved our SSRS server to our data center and noticed that automated reports were not going out. Wondering if anyone else has seen the following after only moving a server and making no other changes:

```
02/08/2022-10:38:04:: e ERROR: Error sending email. Exception: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The function requested is not supported
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.Flush()
   at System.Net.Mail.ReadLinesCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
   at System.Net.Mail.EHelloCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String domain)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider.Deliver(Notification notification)
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL and SSRS

Comment: Looks like services on the new server aren't running under the same security contexts as the old one.

Comment: All services seem to be running fine. We had initial issues getting the server back onto the domain which was causing actual errors logging back into the SSRS portal. All other services are working and we aren't getting anything in the event log. Is there a certain service we should be checking for?

Comment: Since it has already established an SMTP connection in the stack trace (processing `EHLO`) and then it's trying to do TLS stuff I'm guessing it's trying to establish a TLS session with `STARTTLS`. Does the target SMTP mail server support TLS 1.2, or does it only support TLS 1.0 and 1.1? On the SSRS server, in the SCHANNEL registry configuration, are TLS 1.0 and 1.1 enabled, or only TLS 1.2?

Comment: Reference to similar error message: [SSRS: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.Mail will not be resent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/571511/ssrs-a-call-to-sspi-failed-see-inner-exceptionmail.html)

Comment: Reaching out to a TLS 1.2 server (Microsoft 365 with Mimecast) and our SCHANNEL configuration is only TLS 1.2 enabled

Comment: A slightly different error message but very similar stack trace at [SSRS Report subscription error after change to O365 mail server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66854430/ssrs-report-subscription-error-after-change-to-o365-mail-server). Based on SSRS using its own .NET Framework code for TLS connectivity the answer on that question referencing [Configure for strong cryptography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-server#configure-for-strong-cryptography) could be helpful.